# Jenkins can not clone Git repository over Git/SSH on Windows

Tags: windows, git, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I have successfully cloned Git repository in Jenkins over Git/SSH on Windows 2008 32-bit. When I tried to do the same on Windows 2008 64-bit, *Console Output* page gets stuck here:

```
Démarré par l'utilisateur anonymous
Checkout:book / C:\Jenkins\workspace\book - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1da691a
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 5d7ce4ae23c91fb201ee005e6db17bcd795ca965 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checkout:book / C:\Jenkins\workspace\book - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1da691a
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
```

When I stop the build (after a few minutes of being stuck there), I get the rest of the error message:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git@github.com:zeljkofilipin/watirbook.git
ERROR: Cause: Error performing command: C:\Git\bin\git.exe clone --progress -o origin git@github.com:zeljkofilipin/watirbook.git C:\Jenkins\workspace\book
null
Trying next repository
ERROR: Could not clone repository
FATAL: Could not clone
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1042)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:968)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:785)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:767)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:968)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1193)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:567)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:455)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1404)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:230)
```

- I can clone the repository via Git read-only URL `git://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook.git` from Jenkins on both machines
- I can clone via Git/SSH URL `git@github.com:zeljkofilipin/watirbook.git` from the command line on both machines
- I can clone via Git/SSH URL from Jenkins on 32-bit machine, but not on 64-bit machine.

The only difference I can notice between the two machines (not counting that one is a virtual machine on my laptop, and another is a real machine in Switzerland) is that the first one is 32-bit and the second one is 64-bit.

Not sure if that could be related, but 32-bit machine has location set to Croatia, and 64-bit machine to Switzerland (as you can see from Git output in French).

For more information please see my blog post: [Jenkins, Windows and Git](http://filipin.eu/2011/10/21/jenkins-windows-and-git.html)

Comment: The link to your blog post no longer works; you might want to update that :)

Comment: @OwenBlacker thanks for letting me know, I have fixed the broken link.

Comment: Thanks, dude! (I don't appear to be able to tag you in my reply; does Stack Overflow have problems with the háček?)

Comment: @OwenBlacker: "Only one additional user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've gone through these pains recently. Especially frustrating is the lack of error logs in this scenario: probably because MSysgit prompts user on the console when trying to recover - which doesn't get through Jenkins console.

Based on my experience here are a few key elements to watch for:

1. a mix of both Msysgit and Cygwin installed: MSysgit worked better for me- but I assume you're using that too
2. some people have more luck with `<MSYSGIT_ROOT>\cmd\git.cmd` than `<MSYSGIT_ROOT>\bin\git.exe`
3. making sure your slave runs as the same user (which is not the default upon service-based installs).. - oh I see you got that too
4. setting `HOME` variable for windows slaves explicity
5. basically make sure the same .ssh keys are reached when under Jenkins.
6. for debugging, I found it useful to create a test job with no SCM, but run `git clone` in an "Execute shell/batch" build step. That should reveal a bit more info. BTW, you can do an `env` in the same step and maybe `ls %HOME%/.ssh`

I think the above is what gave me a working a Windows 7 64bit Jenkins slave with git support - although I thought this had more to do with some other fine config detail than with 64 vs 32 bits. Good luck anyhow!

Comment: Thanks, will try your suggestions and I will update my question when I fix the problem.

Comment: Setting git to `<MSYSGIT_ROOT>\cmd\git.cmd` instead of `<MSYSGIT_ROOT>\bin\git.exe` fixed the problem.

Comment: Good, and thanks for feedback. (BTW, for some strange reason git.exe works just fine for me :-/

Comment: Maybe that was not the problem. I have uninstalled both Jenkins and Git on both machines and installed clean. Maybe I did something different this time.

Comment: would you like to try with git.exe when you get a chance? also, are  you setting HOME?

Comment: Tried, works with both git.cmd and git.exe. Did not set HOME. So I guess the first time I did something wrong with the Git installation.

Comment: Had problems with this again. Looks like you have to configure Jenkins to use `git.cmd`, cloning over Git/SSH does not work with git.exe.

Comment: "cloning over Git/SSH does not work with git.exe" as I said it does for me, so this might not be a universal truth.. is this still happening on 64 bits?

Comment: Yes, on 64-bit machine. I think Git.exe does not use my ssh key, and git.cmd does. I could probably get git.exe to work with setting HOME and stuff like that, but I did not have the time to try it.

Comment: Fair enough - and yes that's plausible, maybe the reason git.exe works for me. When I figure out the full picture (it's still a bit voodoo for me), I might contribute some clear guidelines to Jenkins guides  - that's why I was wondering.

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin had a similar problem on my setup and indeed setting HOME in the user environment solved the case.

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin: Did you try to do all this through cygwin? I'm setting everything up through cygwin so I set jenkins to use the slave as a Unix slave. Everything works fine, except git cloning just spins away until I kill it (from the jenkins console). Doing it through the cygwin terminal manually works fine. For the life of me I can't figure out the difference.

Answer (score 7):

In the latest version of git, had to use %GIT_HOME%/cmd/git.exe, rather than %GIT_HOME%/bin/git.exe and figuring out the home directory of the user running the jenkins service.

Comment: This issue was bugging me for the last one day. Changing from ...bin/git.exe to ...cmd/git.exe did the trick. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

Another issue i faced with was, ssh.exe was not looking at the `%userprofile%/.ssh` folder for the key files. Instead it was looking to the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh` which was empty and which causes a hang due to ssh authentication prompt on the machine where git repo located.

We just copied the key files under `%userprofile%/.ssh` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh` and the problem is resolved.

Comment: I couldn't get Jenkins credentials to work, popping the file in Git\.ssh (and saying credentials: -none-) worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Notes from a hard learned lesson.
I had problems getting the ssh to work running Jenkins as a named user account for ssh+git.

Here is what I had to do to solve the problem:

1. Generate the key using ssh-keygen (note where they are located)
2. Set "HOME" to this location

I tried with puttygen and GET_SSH=plink that all failed very bad but no clear errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to use any configuration options from a per-user configuration file eg. ~/.ssh/config you can put them in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config, the key files  can be put in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git.ssh

Answer (score 0):

If your account is attached to domain. Then you need to make sure user for which the Jenkins Slave is ran. For the purpose open **Settings**->**Properties** *of "Jenkins Slave"*->**Log On**. and choose necessary ***user*** from ***domain*** for correct execution.

Answer (score 0):

Since my Windows Jenkins was a slave, I needed to configure that node to find the git in cmd instead of bin as described by inger. To do this, go to Manage Jenkins, Manage Nodes, click on the appropriate node, click on Configure and then go to the Tool Locations. Find git in the drop-down and then specify the path to git.exe (including git.exe), like C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe.

I confirmed that the cmd/git.exe worked differently than the bin/git.exe from both command-line and with a temporary jenkins job using the git command (instead of an scm repo).

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin

Just add a ssh-enabled user logon to Jenkins and it should work smoothly.

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.