# Could not clone repository in OpenShift

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, openshift

While pushing my changes to the gear on OpenShift I got the error below.

I have tried to delete my .ssh folders and do the rhc install but it didnt help.

> Warning: Permanently added '.rhcloud.com,' (RSA)
>   to the list of known hosts. Counting objects: 17, done. Delta
>   compression using up to 8 threads. Compressing objects: 100% (8/8),
>   done. Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 756 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. Total
>   9 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: Executing Jenkins build.
>   remote: remote: You can track your build at
>   https://jenkins-yadazing.rhcloud.com/job/-build remote:
>   remote: Waiting for build to
>   schedule..............................................................................Done
>   remote: Waiting for job to
>   complete........................................................................................Done
>   remote: FAILED remote: !!!!!!!! remote: Deployment Halted! remote: If
>   the build failed before the deploy step, your previous remote: build
>   is still running. Otherwise, your application may be remote: partially
>   deployed or inaccessible. remote: Fix the build and try again. remote:
>   !!!!!!!! remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit
>   code: 1) remote: Error message: Failed to execute: 'control
>   post-receive' for /var/lib/openshift//jenkins-client remote:
>   remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command
>   again with the '--trace' option. To
>   ssh://@.rhcloud.com/~/git/.git/
>   cbb5055..00e9aa4 master -> master

Jenkins log shows:

> Started by user Jenkins System Builder Building remotely on GEAR_BLDR
>   in workspace /var/lib/openshift//app-root/runtime/repo
>   Checkout:repo /
>   /var/lib/openshift//app-root/runtime/repo -
>   hudson.remoting.Channel@f3570c:GEAR_BLDR Using strategy: Default Last
>   Built Revision: Revision 99771ffddd1c38592daaabfc95aed193d9163078
>   (origin/origin) Checkout:repo /
>   /var/lib/openshift//app-root/runtime/repo -
>   hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@155c642 WGEAR_IPing out workspace first.
>   Cloning the remote Git repository Cloning repository origin ERROR:
>   Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone
>   ssh://52d83ffa4382ece2a90001d8@.rhcloud.com/~/git/.git
>   ERROR: Cause: Error performing command: git clone --progress -o origin
>   ssh://52d83ffa4382ece2a90001d8@.rhcloud.com/~/git/.git
>   /var/lib/openshift//app-root/runtime/repo Command "git
>   clone --progress -o origin
>   ssh://52d83ffa4382ece2a90001d8@.rhcloud.com/~/git/.git
>   /var/lib/openshift//app-root/runtime/repo" returned
>   status code 128: Cloning into
>   '/var/lib/openshift//app-root/runtime/repo'... ssh:
>   connect to host .rhcloud.com port 22: Connection timed out
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you
>   have the correct access rights and the repository exists. Trying next
>   repository ERROR: Could not clone repository FATAL: Could not clone
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone at
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1042) at
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:968) at
>   hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2387)

I tried to delete the content of .ssh directory and run rhc setup again but that didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the ssh keys that can access the git repo you're trying to clone on your Jenkins gear.

UPDATE:

I actually came across this [Jenkins can not clone Git repository over Git/SSH on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850395/jenkins-can-not-clone-git-repository-over-git-ssh-on-windows) which should help.

Comment: How do I do that?

I have deleted <user>/.ssh folder and executed the rhc setup (see output below) but that didnt help. 

Your private SSH key file should be set as readable only to yourself.  Please run 'chmod 600 C:<USER_NAME>\.ssh\id_rsa'

Checking for a domain ... <DOMAIN_NAME>

Checking for applications ... found 5

  <GEAR_NAME_1>    http://<GEAR_NAME_1>.rhcloud.com/
  <GEAR_NAME_2>   http://<GEAR_NAME_2>.rhcloud.com/
  <GEAR_NAME_3>   http://<GEAR_NAME_3>.rhcloud.com/
  <GEAR_NAME_4> http://<GEAR_NAME_4>.rhcloud.com/
  
Your client tools are now configured.

Comment: If you deleted your .ssh directory then you also deleted your private ssh key. Generate a new one, run rhc setup and you should be able to proceed.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and deleted my .ssh, executed rhc setup to generate the new keys. I also checked in something to kick the build on Jenkins.

but I am getting the same build error: 
"Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

Answer (score 0):

From the jenkins log:

```
ssh: connect to host <GEAR_NAME>.rhcloud.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Jenkins tried to run `ssh` to connect to that host and port, but it never got a response to the TCP connection attempt. The usual explanation for this error is that some firewall or other other network device is blocking access from the client to the server, or the GEAR_NAME server was down at the time.